# Whats the Rebus equivalent of NServiceBus RegisterWebCallback? (if any)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rebus

I am used to register callbacks from within ASP/MVC applications in order to get notified of responses to events send/published. In order to do so, NServiceBus provides some methods (Register/RegisterWebCallback) which can be invoked on the IAsync context which is returned by bus.Send(..).

Is it there any equivalent on Rebus side?  I could define an IHandleMessage and then manually do internal dispatching of received responses, but it seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I never really got why NServiceBus would allow you to register an in-memory callback when calling `bus.Send`.

I've actually only seen it used in weird hacky scenarios where people use it to implement a blocking request/response API by waiting on the wait handle of the returned `IAsyncResult`.

Is it something that you're seriously missing?

How would you use it?

Comment: My tipical use-case is during a Reply/Response from an ASP.MVC controller. It allows me to request something to other component and wait a few seconds for an answer (or give up and asume a timeout).

Comment: Think of asking a component if it's alive in order to show it to a user as response to a web request. (it's not my current case, but it may be a valid example).

Comment: Last, but not least, we normally do it using AsynControllers, where being able to register a callback which allows decreasing outstanding operations once a response from bus is received, fits nicelly.

Comment: Right :) but it's not currently something that I'm contemplating on adding to the core API. It could probably easily be made though, as a configuration extension that uses Rebus' hooks...

Comment: I would have loved to have made a prototype for this, but I'm kind of busy these days - I'll be happy to help you out though if you feel like looking into it!

Comment: May main issue is having access to a message's unique-id or correlation-id before it get's transmitted to the wire. So I can temporarilly save such id to match it to incoming replies, w/o a race condition.

Comment: Hi again Pablo! I had a few free minutes, and I used them to implement a prototype of inline callbacks - if you're interested, you can check out the code from here: https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/tree/feature-web-async

Comment: But please note that I had to add a feature to Rebus core in order for this to be as smooth as possible, so you'll need to include both Rebus.dll and Rebus.WebAsync.dll from the branch in order for this to work

Comment: We've been doing a few tests on your changes this last week, and it mostly works fine, however we've found a couple of issues. What would be the best place to followup on them? here? an issue on github?

Comment: Cool! - please report the issues on GitHub

Comment: Rebus.WebAsync may seem a bit misleading as name, as we would be using this not only from web, but also con monitoring processes and console tools. ;)

Comment: Yeah, but it's so hard to rename projects in VS! (but I will rename it, I promise :))

Comment: Is this call back idea abandoned? I too would see a use case for this. Imagine a web request, representing a command. The web request handler would send a command message over a message bus, that would be handled on a different endpoint, possibly with re-tries (making sure the command message it handled at least once), and once done it would reply with "command message handling done", and the web request handler would resume execution. Advantages: the command message handler would be re-tried in a case of an error, and web handler would complete when the handling is done.

Comment: Rebus (core) has abandoned that idea, yes. But Rebus has an add-on called [Rebus.Async](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Async) that implements a "synchronous" protocol where you can `var response = await bus.SendRequest(request);`, which then (asynchronously) blocks the caller until the response is received. You can use that to implement this functionality.